# Exporting java body with imagine into jar w/ images

Tags: java, jar

I wrote code that works whenever i run in Eclipse, but whenever i try to export it into a runnable Jar, my images dont show up.

For my images this is the code being used `pic1=ImageIO.read(FourCournersRunner.class.getResource("/Images/1.png"));` 
When exporting the project I've chosen "Package required libraries into generated JAR":

Comment: See inside the jar (is a zip file), and check the path. It must be case sensitive (in a jar and under Linux). Check the URL too: null = is not found.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please also show the code where you display the image in GUI, the problem might lie in there.
2. Did you also package the `Images` folder to the .jar file?
3. The problem might be caused by the way you set up build path too.

In short, I don't think the code you provide right now can reproduce the problem.